# react routes and navhashlink issue

Tags: reactjs

I'm using navhashlinks im my app along with react router, but the problem I'm encountering is that since I am providing a '#element' to the navhashlink, it isnt getting matched to the route path, therefore the activeclassname isn't being applied.
For example,

```
<NavHashLink to='/home#bottom'}  activeClassName='activelink' >

</NavHashLink>
 <NavHashLink to='/home'}  activeClassName='activelink' >

</NavHashLink>
```

I'm trying to make so that both of these links are active
And the Route would be

```
     <Route path='/home'>
        
      </Route>
```

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link)? Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces your issue we could live debug in?

Comment: Sure, one second

Comment: For some reason when i create a new sandbox it works, but cant figure out what is wrong with the code in my original app

Comment: Ok i have figured out what the issue was, here is the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/live/g5zwftp

Comment: So are you saying the codesandbox reproduces the issue? Seems to be linking to a hashlink from what I can tell. `to="/home#divhome"` worked on the home page and after I added a similar div with id for the library page the `to="/library#divlibrary"` hashlink worked as well.Oh, I see, you are referring to the link being active.

Comment: yea, they aren't being active but they return to the same page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

It seems that even though the the root path is the same, the nav links are looking for deeper equality between the two routes, and thus they are unique matches. It looks like the `NavHashLink` with the hash link has populated `hash` property in the `location` object.

## Solution

You can use the [isActive](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink/isactive-func) prop function to provide your own path matching logic between links that route to the same page.

```
<NavHashLink
  to="/library#divlibrary"
  smooth
  activeStyle={{ color: "red" }}
  isActive={(match, location) => {
    return match?.url === location?.pathname
  }}
>
  To library{" "}
</NavHashLink>
<NavHashLink
  to="/library"
  activeStyle={{ color: "red" }}
  isActive={(match, location) => {
    return match?.url === location?.pathname
  }}
  >
  To Library
</NavHashLink>
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-routes-and-navhashlink-issue]

[image]